# Django SQL injection in GET requests

Tags: python, django, django-views, sql-injection

One of the SAST tools has flagged the below piece of code as vulnerable on SQL injection grounds, I want to know why does it show vulnerable although Django documents says that all inputs are type safe converted/ bad inputs are escaped in backend, file is views.py:

```
def infopanel(request):
item_id     = request.GET.get('item_id','')
change_key  = request.GET.get('change_key','')
context     = request.GET.get('context','')
if item_id == '' or change_key == '':
    return render_to_response('emailtrackergenericfailure.html',{'errorcode':"invalid message parameters (item_id, change_key, and or folder)"},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# The exchange server item id sometimes has a '+' character in it.
# '+' is read as a ' ' due to the way the GET parameters are formatted.
# Change all spaces in the strings back to a '+' to repair this.
item_id     = replace(item_id   ,' ','+')
change_key  = replace(change_key,' ','+')

#return render_to_response('emailtrackergenericfailure.html',{'errorcode':'ahhhh'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))    

message = getMessage(item_id,change_key)
# print "****************** MESSAGE ******************"
# print message
# print "**************** END MESSAGE ****************"


#return render_to_response('emailtrackergenericfailure.html',{'errorcode':message},context_instance=RequestContext(request))    

# Find the email message object and mark it as read
mssg = None
folder = ""
try: 
    mssg = Inbox.objects.get(item_id__exact=item_id,change_key=change_key)
    folder = 'inbox'
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    try:
        mssg = TicketEmail.objects.get(item_id=item_id,change_key=change_key)
        folder = 'ticketemails'
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        try:
            mssg = SentItems.objects.get(item_id=item_id,change_key=change_key)
            folder = 'sentitems'
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            try:
                mssg = RequestEmail.objects.get(item_id=item_id,change_key=change_key)
                folder = 'requests'
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                try:
                    mssg = DeletedItems.objects.get(item_id=item_id,change_key=change_key)
                    folder = 'deleteditems'
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return render_to_response('emailtrackergenericfailure.html',{'errorcode':'message not found in database.'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# Check if the exchange server returned an error
if message.GetItemResponseMessage._ResponseClass != 'Success':
    mssg.read='True'
    mssg.save()
    return render_to_response('emailtrackergenericfailure.html',{'errorcode':message.GetItemResponseMessage.ResponseCode},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


if mssg.read != 'True':
    new_change_key = markAsRead(item_id,change_key)
    mssg.read='True'
    mssg.change_key=new_change_key
    mssg.save()
```

Comment: Is this the complete view? You don't return a response if the if-statement is false. If this is the complete view, it does not interact with the database, so the view itself is not vulnerable to SQL injection. I can't tell about other parts (such as the template).

Comment: @knbk please see the entire function